# How to navigate from a sheet to a full screen

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationstack

I am trying to use a navigation link within a sheet, however whenever I do it, I navigate within the sheet itself instead of a new full view.

Sheet Picture:

[image]

Navigation Picture:

[image]

My current code looks like this, but I can't figure out how to navigate to a fullview rather than a sheet.

```
struct ContentView2: View {
    @State private var sheetDisplayed = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Show Sheet") {
                sheetDisplayed.toggle()
            }.sheet(isPresented: $sheetDisplayed) {
                NavigationStack {
                    NavigationLink(destination: SheetView(), label: {
                        Text("Go to view")
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SheetView : View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("View One")
    }
}
```

See images for what this outputs.

Comment: — I hate when people do what I'm about to do! LOL  **I'm no expert, *but*** I think you need to move your `NavigationStack` into your main body and leave the `NavigationLink` where it is.

Comment: Perhaps provide a more complete chunk of code so others can copy, play, and test it to ensure you receive the best help.

Comment: Simply put: you can't do what you want. You can present the entire view as `fullScreenCover` (then it's not a sheet per se, but ok), and then you can navigate in full screen. You could also close the sheet and navigate in the main navigation. Might be confusing. But you can not start a "full screen navigation" from a sheet. Also: it would be super confusing for a user.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the .fullScreenCover modifier instead of .sheet
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/fullscreencover(ispresented:ondismiss:content:)